# Observing attributes using Observer

Tags: java, observer-pattern

Can I get **which attribute changed** using `Observer` and `Observable` and **what was the old value** in Java?

`notifyObservers` only gets one attribute which is the new value.

Answer (score 2):

In the method notifyObservers(Object obj) you can pass any Object to your Observer.
You can use this Object as a container for any data you would like to communicate (like the old or new value).
You just need to cast it back in the Observer and of you go.

Comment: that will work about the Old and new values. But how should I "pass" the __argument which changed__?

Comment: You can put a String or Enum with the name if you really need that. But i would consider not to do that, just update your full view.